# Linkedin Omniauth gem 'omniauth-linkedin-oauth2' giving Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linkedin-api, omniauth, omniauth-linkedin

I have an application running with successful **Google** and **Facebook** omniauthentication running. I want to add Linkedin Login too with omniauth. All seems to fine until I request the **email address** by adding **:scope => 'r_emailaddress'** to the line

**devise.rb**

```
  config.omniauth :linkedin, ENV['LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET'], :scope => 'r_emailaddress', :fields => ['email', 'id', 'first-name', 'last-name']
```

All seems to be correct if I removed the **r_emailaddress** and add any other scope like **r_liteprofile** as

```
  config.omniauth :linkedin, ENV['LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET'], :scope => 'r_liteprofile', :fields => ['email', 'id', 'first-name', 'last-name']
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'omniauth-linkedin-oauth2'
```

The error is coming up in the backend and in the front end after successfully putting all the credentials on the Linkedin page, the app is redirecting to the home page and not giving any error in the UI.

The error it's throwing in the logs is

```
ERROR -- omniauth: (linkedin) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, : 
{"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Not enough permissions to access: GET /me","status":403}
```

It would be great if anyone can help me in this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove scope and fields both and try this:

```
config.omniauth :linkedin, ENV['LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET']
```

Comment: Thanks, that means we have to remove both, **scope** and **fields** to get this work.